# Running Multiple Methods At Once In Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a method which has an infinite loop in it to create a video display. This method is called within another loop that handles hardware input and as such cannot loop as fast as the video, causing lag if I use the outer loop to run the video. Is there a way to start the video loop and then start the hardware loop and run them separately? Currently if I call the video loop it just sits at that loop until it returns.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Python's own [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module, or a cooperative microthreading module like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/).

Note that Python's threading mechanism carries this disclaimer for CPython (the default Python implementation on most boxes):

> Due to the Global Interpreter Lock, in CPython only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better of use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use `multiprocessing`. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

Depending on how the underlying modules you are calling operate, you may find that while using `threading`, one thread won't give up control very often, if at all.  In that case, using cooperative microthreading might be your only option.

Comment: Sorry I had to rip off your first line :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Python's own [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Note that Multiprocessing does not have to fight the GIL and can work simultaneously for everything you give it to do.

On the other hand there is a warning with the multiprocessing module, when you spawn a process it is a completely separate python interpreter. So its not just a OS controlled thread. It is in itself an entirely different process. This can add overhead to programs but the advantage of completely dodging the GIL makes this only a mild issue.

Comment: Yup, this can work too.  It's worth noting however that the communication mechanisms you have to use become cross-process instead of cross-thread and are therefore not as simple as sharing objects, since each process gets its own heap.