# What is the best way to run multiple functions at the same time in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am searching to read a file (.txt) and give my other functions the different lines in order, it's a pipeline (RISC) with 5 stages. the first instruction in the file is given to the fist stage in my pipeline, and then instruction continues to the other stages, i want that after my first stage is finished processing the first instruction to give it the next one and process it in parallel with the other stages.

my current code without the possibility to run parallel functions:

```
leng = length(txt)  # how many instructions to process
for _ in range(leng): to process every instruction but sequentially
    stage_first(arguments)
    stage_second(arguments) # and after the other stages
```

i would like something where it would give the first instruction to first stage, this instruction continue down the stages but right after that the first stage is finished with the instruction, it will receive the 2nd instruction without waiting for the other stages.

Comment: You can use joblib library to make use of all the processors.https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Multiple Methods At Once In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299526/running-multiple-methods-at-once-in-python)